# How to query a TFS build from its URI using the api?

Tags: build, tfs, tfs-sdk

How do I get the IBuildDetail object from TFS using the the builds URI?

e.g. the URI is vstfs:///Build/Build/1546

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the GetBuild() method on the build server class. It takes a Uri as a parameter.

```
var buildDetail= buildServer.GetBuild(new Uri(builduri));
```